# Exposing a Dependency Property I was created previously

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

I am working in WPF and I am creating some userControl which some of them are inside others.

In the code behind of one of my userControls I created a dependency property as below:
(MyInnerControl.xaml.cs)

```
public static DependencyProperty MyDependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MyProperty",
        typeof(Object),
        typeof(MyInnerControl));

public Object MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return (Object)GetValue(MyDependencyProperty );
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MyDependencyProperty , value);
        }
    }
...
...
```

And this property works perfectly, But then I try to expose this dependency in another userControl as below:

In my code behind of my container userControl:
(MyContainerControl.xaml.cs)

```
    public static DependencyProperty MyExternalDependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MyExternalProperty",
        typeof(Object),
        typeof(MyContainerControl));

public Object MyExternalProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return (Object)GetValue(MyExternalDependencyProperty );
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MyExternalDependencyProperty , value);
        }
    }
...
...
```

And in my XAML:
(MyContainerControl.xaml)

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControls.MyContainerControl" Name="this"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="329" d:DesignWidth="535" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyInnerControls">
<Grid>
    <my:MyInnerControl Margin="6,25,6,35" MyProperty="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=MyExternalProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
...
...
```

Finaly I add MyContainerControl to a grid and do the binding to my viewModel as below:
(AnotherContainer.xaml)

```
...
<MyContainerControl MyExternalProperty="{Binding MyExternalProperty}"/>
...
```

**My problem is that my ExternalProperty does not get or set any value. What am I doing wrong?**

Just to clarify, my DataContext is properly set.

Hope someone can help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any binding errors? They show up in the Output in Visual Studio when debugging. You might also want to use something like Snoop WPF which can drill down into your UI components and look at the bindings and whatnot.

Comment: @Tim I just ran the program again to watch the Output window, but I dont get any error message

Comment: I don't really like the fact that you called your user control `this`, as it's a reserved keyword. Did you try using a different name for your control?

Comment: I agree with Lester. That might even cause a problem beyond just being code smell. I'm not sure.

Comment: @Lester @Tim I have tried what Lester said, however, I have some other properties which works perfectly. So, I think `this` is not the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that the problem is caused by the fact that you're not following the Dependency Property naming conventions, which is to set your dependency property name to `<ProperyName>Property` (e.g. `MyExternalProperty`) and using a CLR property wrapper with the same name, but omitting the "Property" suffix (in this case, `MyExternal`). Following this convention should solve your problems.

From [MSDN - Dependency Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx):

> The naming convention of the property and its backing
>   DependencyProperty field is important. The name of the field is always
>   the name of the property, with the suffix Property appended. For more
>   information about this convention and the reasons for it, see Custom
>   Dependency Properties.

**EDIT: A few more things:**

1. Your dependency property registration is wrong: you're passing `"MyProperty"` instead of `"MyDependency"` and `"MyExternalProperty"` instead of `"MyExternalDependency"`
2. You should avoid using `this` as a name for any of your controls, as it's a reserved keyword.

Comment: I have made the corrections you suggested but it is still not working.

Comment: @Dante This works fine for me. How do you know it's not being set? Let me remind you that breakpoints in the wrapper properties won't be triggered by setting the property via XAML. You can make sure the binding works by displaying a textblock in your inner control that binds to the inner property.

Comment: Since my viewModel implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, in my property which is binded, I show a `MessageBox` in the `set { ... }`, but this `MessageBox` never show up

Comment: @Dante As I said, setting the property via XAML won't execute the wrapper property's setter. If you want to, you can register for changes when registering the dependency property itself like this:
`public static DependencyProperty MyInnerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyInner",typeof(Object),typeof(MyInnerControl),new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((d, e) => { MessageBox.Show("Property Changed"); }));`

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but Im talking about the property in my ViewModel class, which is the DataContex of my UserControl, and I know it is a way to know if a binding is working because I am doing the same with other porperties

Answer (score 0):

You should give your UserControl an x:Name and use that value for ElementName

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControls.MyContainerControl" Name="this"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     mc:Ignorable="d" 
     x:Name="ThisUserControl"
     d:DesignHeight="329" d:DesignWidth="535" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyInnerControls">
<Grid>
    <my:MyInnerControl Margin="6,25,6,35" MyProperty="{Binding ElementName=ThisUserControl, Path=MyExternalProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

...
...

Comment: Just tested it works ok my end, two nested usercontrols, does not work when I substitute "ElementName=this" instead of the above suggestion, not sure what "ElementName=this" is wasn't able to find it anywhere